Downloading satellite raster data using Earth engine lib in python
I'm using the following code to download satellite imagery for the given polygon. The script runs successfully,  but I don't get the files downloaded in the drive. What could be the reason?
 import ee
 import os
 from datetime import datetime

 try:
     ee.Initialize()
 except Exception as e:
     ee.Authenticate()
     ee.Initialize()


 def download_satellite_images(region_coords, start_date, end_date, download_folder, cloud_cover=10):


roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(region_coords)


collection = (
    ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
 .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", cloud_cover))
)


image_list = collection.toList(collection.size())
image_count = image_list.size().getInfo()

if image_count == 0:
    print("No images found for the specified criteria.")
    return

print(f"Found {image_count} images. Starting download...")


os.makedirs(download_folder, exist_ok=True)


for i in range(image_count):
    image = ee.Image(image_list.get(i))
    image_id = image.id().getInfo()
    image_date = image.date().format("YYYY-MM-dd").getInfo()
    filename = f"{image_date}_{image_id}.tif"
    filepath = os.path.join(download_folder, filename)

    
    task= ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(
        image=image.clip(roi),
        description=filename,
        folder=download_folder,
        scale=10,  
        region=roi.getInfo()["coordinates"],
        fileFormat="GeoTIFF",
    )

    task.start()
    print(f"Started download task for {filename}")

 if __name__ == "__main__":

     region_coordinates = [
    [78.547606, 11.670881],
    [78.583869, 11.670881],
    [78.583869, 11.649485],
    [78.547606, 11.649485],
    [78.547606, 11.670881],
] 

start_date = "2024-06-01"
end_date = "2024-12-01"
download_dir = "satellite_images"

download_satellite_images(
    region_coords=region_coordinates,
    start_date=start_date,
    end_date=end_date,
    download_folder=download_dir,
    cloud_cover=10,
)

The output:
Found 11 images. Starting download...
Started download task for 2024-06-01_20240601T050649_20240601T051727_T44PKU.tif
Started download task for 2024-06-16_20240616T050701_20240616T051417_T43PHN.tif... so on

please specify your python versions, OS (windows/linux/mac/....) name a version  (i can't reproduce this on python 3.12.2 and the ee version has references to pre python 3 modules (StringIO for starters). ..... tks
